# Using Hystrix with Spring Data Repositories

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, hystrix

Given that one of the main benefits of Spring Data and the related REST repositories is that most of the time the developer doesn't have to worry about the underlying implementations, is there an **out-of-the-box** way to leverage the Spring Cloud Netflix libraries, specifically the Hystrix annotations in this case, without extending every call in the provided Repository interfaces or  creating my own implementation?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about with Hystrix.  The circuit breaker is implemented on each resource that needs to be monitored.

Comment: @ccit-spence Right. Spring Data Rest exports those resources automatically.  How would one set up circuit breakers for those resources?

Comment: The difference I think is how they are intended.  Each service is not really worried about itself, more the service they are trying to connect to at any given time.  The circuit breaker is for the remote repository not the local.

Comment: @ccit-spence That makes sense. I may just be misinterpreting the intention here, which would explain my question. I'll leave this open for a bit longer, as I'd be interested in seeing if there's an answer anyway. :-)

Comment: Agreed, obviously this is just my opinion.  I have been playing around with Spring Cloud since around October.  Learning as I go :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you need to wrap calls in another service whose methods are annotated with `@HystrixCommand`. Because of the way both Spring Data and the Hystrix Aspect work (they both create proxies), there would need to be specific integration in Spring Data for `@HystrixCommand`. @ccit-spence is right, you really want to put `@HystrixCommand` on the services calling into a Spring Data REST repository.